# Plot a sum of vectors using inline free format or wolframalpha. What is the hidden code?

Tags: plotting, vector, wolfram-alpha-queries

Using Wolframalpha or  inline free format you can obtain a nice representation of a sum of vectors. An example is shown below.
Whish is  the hidden code? (or a code that make the same representation). I can make it using Graphics and Arrow but is too long, I suppose there is a easy way to do it. I think in one of the last Mathematica version has been included a build-up function to make it.

= plot vector(1,1) + vector(2,3)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
WolframAlpha["plot vector(1,1)+vector(2,3)", {{"Result", 1}, "Content"}]
```

[image]

To see the code behind you can take the first `Part`:

```
WolframAlpha["plot vector(1,1)+vector(2,3)", {{"Result", 1}, "Content"}][[1]]
```

[image]

To get the main graphics, use

```
WolframAlpha["plot vector(1,1)+vector(2,3)", {{"Result", 1}, "Content"}][[1, 1, 
   1, 1, 1]] // RawBoxes
```

[image]

and to get the legend use

```
WolframAlpha["plot vector(1,1)+vector(2,3)", {{"Result", 1}, "Content"}][[1, 1, 
   1, 1, 2]] // RawBoxes
```

[image]

To get the result pane with special styling, use

```
WolframAlpha["plot vector(1,1)+vector(2,3)", IncludePods -> "Result", 
 AppearanceElements -> {"Pods"}]
```

[image]